# loginview change data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, mdf, loginview

I have recently created an asp.net page in visual studio 2010.  I have not changed any of the prebuilt loginview code.  It creates the MDF file that allows for logging in users and registering users.  However, I don't want to use the MDF file, I want to use a SQL Server instance i have running (lets call it MyServer) with a database MyDatabase.  Where is the code that connects to the MDF file and is there a clean way of changing the data source?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your `string connection` in your `config file`  `(Web.config)`

Modify this section

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=../File.mdf; Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True;Trusted_Connection=Yes"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

With for example this

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Link : http://www.connectionstrings.com/